# Problem with response option : WordPress Watson

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am creating a chatbot Watson integrated with a WordPress module on my website. When I test my bot with Watson everything goes well. I use answers with options. These answers correctly redirect me to the nodes that correspond to the entity.
However, when I test the bot with the WordPress module, the bot does not recognize the answers by options.

How to correct the problem?

Comment: provide more details

Comment: Détail : I create a dialog flow with one question and different response option.
I created the entities to enter in dialog nodes corresponding to the entity. When I test with ibm, I click on one of the options, the bot redirects me correctly in the dialog node corresponding to the created entity. However when I do the same thing with the wordpress module, it does not work.

Comment: Is the wordpress module using the correct API version?

Comment: I do have the right version of the wordpress module. What is surprising is that some options work. I explain: I ask a question: what kind of coffee do you want? answer option: espresso, double espresso, coffee with milk. If I click on one of the choices I am redirected to the corresponding node. Once in the knot I ask a question: So you want a coffee latte? Option answer yes / no. And it does not work ...